# No Maintenance Plans Folder in SQL Studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, maintenance

A client has SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on a Windows 2003 R2 32-bit server.

Under Management in SQL Studio 2008 R2, **there is no maintenance plans folder**. It is not under Management --> Legacy either, as it would be if there were legacy-mode databases on the server. **I am certain this is SQL Server 2008 R2 and not Express.** I have checked the version and verified the splash screen when studio starts are not Express. I am logging in as the SQL account sa, and the account does have the sysadmin server role.

Lastly, right clicking on a database in SSMS and navigating to "Tasks" does not show any Maintenance Plan option.

Clearly, I'm missing something, and Google is coming up empty considering the scenario I've outlined. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** select @@version returns "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (Intel X86)   Apr 22 2011 11:57:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)"

Answer (score 9):

Express Edition (the free version of SQL Server) doesn't have maintenance plans because it has no SQL Server Agent.  Agent is the constantly-running-scheduler that kicks off jobs like maintenance plans.

Answer (score 1):

Run and check the following:

```
USE MSDB
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_subplans
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_plans
```

If "sysmaintplan_plans" is empty check if the folderid for the maintenance folder is 
08AA12D5-8F98-4DAB-A4FC-980B150A5DC8

```
select * from sysssispackagefolders where foldername ='Maintenance Plans'
```

If it is not the above id update the folderid like this and new maintenance plans will be shown correct.

```
update sysssispackagefolders
set folderid = '08AA12D5-8F98-4DAB-A4FC-980B150A5DC8'
where foldername ='Maintenance Plans'
```

It worked for me with an SQL Server 2008 R2

Cheers Peter

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

THE STANDARD EDITION, To create or manage maintenance plans, you must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role. Object Explorer only displays the Maintenance Plans node for users who are members of the sysadmin fixed server role.  You can find more information on this subject at [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was that the SQL Server Agent wasn't running on the server. Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure SQL Server Agent is running. Before doing that you may have to open it's properties and set the Start Mode to Automatic and save the changes.