# No maintenance folder under management in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have tried so many queries, solution, suggestion but still I did not get Maintenance plan folder under management folder. According to [Peter's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/no-maintenance-plans-folder-in-sql-studio-2008-r2) I have ran query my folderid is not empty I got **08AA12D5-8F98-4DAB-A4FC-980B150A5DC8** but I do not have maintenance plan folder under Management folder. Please help me How to create Maintenance plan folder.

I am using SQL Server Express. `SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin');` returns 1.

Answer (score 2):

From the same [link you referenced](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/no-maintenance-plans-folder-in-sql-studio-2008-r2) in your question, See Brent Ozar's response

> Express Edition (the free version of SQL Server) doesn't have
>   maintenance plans because it has no SQL Server Agent. Agent is the
>   constantly-running-scheduler that kicks off jobs like maintenance
>   plans.

See also [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698)